# Vocabulary: path in a graph of objects?

Tags: reference, path, graph, terminology, vocabulary

I'm having trouble with the following sentence:

> `DeepClone` performs a deep clone of
>   the target object, stopping the cloning process
>   when all *<dependency paths>* have
>   reached a value type or an `ITransactionalObject`.

What I mean by "dependency path" is the chain of references you follow in the cloning process: object A has a reference to B, B to C, C to D,... and N to an `ITransactionalObject`, and then you stop there and don't clone the `ITransactionalObject`. Then you go back to M and follow that path, and so on, until all branches run into value types or `ITransactionalObjects`.

What term would you use rather than *dependency path*? I have the feeling there must already be a name for it.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path is the standard term for a walk through a graph, so unless you want to add more domain-specific terminology I think that's okay.

You could say "... until the dependency tree is fully resolved (i.e. all paths have terminated in `ITransactionalObject`s or value types)".